# How to call an external argument with an attribute

Tags: python

I am trying to setup a relay module that I can call in other python scripts to activate the relays. I have created this simple script called relay.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import required Python libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Use BCM GPIO references instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# GPIO assigned relay pin numbers for peripherals

light = 35
waterPump = 33
fanMotor = 31

pinList = [light, waterPump, fanMotor]

for i in pinList:
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)

def relayOn(peripheral):
          GPIO.output(peripheral, GPIO.LOW)

def relayOff(peripheral):
          GPIO.output(peripheral, GPIO.HIGH)
```

If I want to activate the relay inside the script by calling:

```
relayOn(light)
```

The script runs fine. but my issue happens when I try to run the script from another python script. For example I made a test file called relayTester.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import relay

relay.relayOn(light)
```

If I run this script I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'light' is not defined
```

I apologize for the newb question. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Does `relay.relayOn(relay.light)` work?

Comment: Wow that did work! Would it be too brazen to ask how that worked?

Comment: I posted an answer with explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use: 
`relay.relayOn(relay.light)`

This is because `light` is a global variable defined in the context of your `relay` module.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
from relay import relayOn, light
```

Then just use:

```
relayOn(light)
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm able to.